# Add static number in the for loop index with PHP

Tags: php, for-loop

I have following for loop code in PHP

```
for($i=10; $i<=50; $i=$i+10)
        {
            echo $i;
        }
```

it will print
10 20 30 40 50

I want to add some specific $i value such as
$i=15 and $i=28

So it shold print
10 15 20 28 30 40 50

How should I edit the code ?

Answer (score 4):

If you want specific values, you should make an array with those values and iterate through it:

```
$vals = array(10, 15, 20, 28, 30, 40, 50);
foreach ($vals as $i) {
    echo $i;
}
```

Comment: I like this, though depending on the size of the array I would have opted for `$vals = array_merge(range(10,50,10), array(15, 28)); sort($vals);`

Answer (score 2):

if you have fixed place where to show these values .. then you can use simple if

```
    for($i=10; $i<=50; $i=$i+10)
    {

         echo $i;
        if($i == 10)
        {
          echo '15';
        }
        if($i == 20)
        {
           echo '28';
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, i'll play the "interview question" game :

```
for($i=10; $i<=50; $i++) {
    if ($i % 10 === 0) {
        echo $i;
    }
    else if ($i === 15 || $i === 28) {
        echo $i;
    }
}
```

Result at http://codepad.org/JBPkm8W1

You can improve this answer by adding an "allowed values" table :

```
$allowed = array (15, 28); // List here all the non % 10 value you want to print
for($i=10; $i<=50; $i++) {
    if ($i % 10 === 0) {
        echo $i;
    }
    else if (in_array($i, $allowed)) {
        echo $i;
    }
}
```

The result at http://codepad.org/w8Erv17K

Comment: This is also useful, no need to create initial array. Thanks so much. :-). Love PHP.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use a `foreach` loop like @WaleedKhan wrote.

To prepare the array you can use `for` loop like you did:

```
$vals = array(); 
for($i = 10; $i <= 50; $i = $i + 10){
  $vals[] = $i;
  }
$vals[] = 15;
$vals[] = 28;
sort($vals);
foreach(...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$extra      = array(15,28);
$res        = array();
for($i=10; $i<=50; $i=$i+10){
    $res[]  = $i;
}

$result     = array_merge($res,$extra);
sort($result);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put the 15 and 28 values in array and get the values using array_intersect.

Create an array to hold the 15 and 28 values (intermeditate values).

```
$new_vals = array(15,28);
```

Now in your for loop you can call array_insersect function to get the intermediate values. Your final code will look like this.

```
$new_vals = array(15,28);

for($i=10; $i<=50; $i=$i+10)
{
    echo $i;
    $val_range = range($i,$i+10);
    $new_array = array_intersect($new_vals , $val_range);
    foreach($new_array as $value)
    {
        echo $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
function EchoLoopStuff($start, $to, $step) {
  for($i=$start; $i<=$to; $i=$i+$step) {
    echo $i;
  }
}
```

But you'd need to add some checking to save yourself from issues when inputs contradict.

Comment: I think it not like that, because it will print number in each step. What I want is add extra step (As you can see I want 2 special number 15 and 28 include in the loop).

Comment: Yes, but each step will be 'valid' because it 'skips' the in betweens (i.e. with a step of `10` there won't be 7, 8, 9 etc).